# Controlled cloth rip/tear

Tags: cloth-simulation

Hello blender stack exchange.

I'm looking for a way to have a controlled tear.
Like as if i'm (tool) ripping vertices one by one or as a group in between frames.
But preferably something i can trigger or include in a key frame.

Think the seam of your butt splitting for bending over too far.
Or the star shape when a lion jumps through the covered hoop in the circus.
I've not mastered vertex groups enough to get it to work.
Neither have i head any success with seams.

Anyway, sorry for the lack of Jargon, i don't know what im looking for or what it's called.

Thanks for expanding my knowledge with yours!

Comment: Not a strong point for blender. You can find a few tutorials like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6NJp0Zaay0) and there is a [paid addon](https://blendermarket.com/products/clothfx--dynamic-cloth-tearing-system) that is meant to make it easier.